# I need a way to make the component render conditionally

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, conditional-statements, render

I'm still new to react and I'm making a decision tree and I got the buttons to render and make them move down to the next question but now I want it to jump to certain parts of the array depending on how they answer (true or false).

for example, I want question[0] to jump to [6] as a response if they answer yes(true)

i was thinking of trying to use if then statements, just not sure if my code makes that harder or easier to do.

```
  const questions = [
    {
      questionText: "Is the account data entry?",
      answerOptions: [
        {answerText: "No", isCorrect: false},
        {answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true},
      ],
    },
    {
      questionText: "Is this customer 1 or 2?",
      answerOptions: [
        {answerText: "No", isCorrect: false},
        {answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true},
      ],
    },
    {
      questionText: "Is it someone with a Power of Attorney or Conservatorship for the Customer?",
      answerOptions: [
        {answerText: "No", isCorrect: false},
        {answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true},
      ],
    },
    {
      questionText: "Is it someone with a signed 'Name Add Form' on file?",
      answerOptions: [
        {answerText: "No", isCorrect: false},
        {answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true},
      ],
    },
    {
      questionText: "Is it someone who is verbally authorized by a verified account holder to speak?",
      answerOptions: [
        {answerText: "No", isCorrect: false},
        {answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true},
      ],
    },
    { //this is object number 5
      questionText: "VERIFIED",
      answerOptions: [

      ],
    },
    { //this is object number 6
      questionText: "You can tell the customer their verbal password.",
      answerOptions: [

      ],
    },
  ]

  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);

  const handleAnswerButton = () => {
    const nextQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
    setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
  }

  return (  
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{questions[currentQuestion].questionText}</h1>
      
      <div className="answerSection">
        {questions[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map((answerOption)=> (
        <button onClick={handleAnswerButton}>{answerOption.answerText}</button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Are you wanting to move the question that is answered `true` to index 6 in the array of questions (mutating the questions array) or are you wanting to 'jump to' question 6 if any of the previous questions are answered `true`?

Comment: I can see how it can be confusing, (I'm still new to it) yes the questions array is polluted with the answers as well. Bad practice I know. I'm open to better ways of handling this. It's all good knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to achieve a decision tree based on selected option, then you can have the next question details mapped with the respective option.

Add `nextQuestionIndex` parameter to the answerOption object.

```
const questions = [
    {
      questionText: "Is the account data entry?",
      answerOptions: [
        {answerText: "No", isCorrect: false, nextQuestionIndex: 1},
        {answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true, nextQuestionIndex: 6},
      ],
    }
]
```

And modify `handleAnswerButton` function to receive `answerOption` object as input. Based on the selected option's `nextQuestionIndex`, navigate to the respective question

```
const handleAnswerButton = (answerOption) => {
    const nextQuestion = answerOption.nextQuestionIndex;
    setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
}
```

Modify the `onClick` function to pass `answerOption` as parameter,

```
<div className="answerSection">
        {questions[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map((answerOption)=> (
        <button onClick={()=>handleAnswerButton(answerOption)}>{answerOption.answerText}</button>
        ))}
</div>
```

Fully working code,

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export default function App() {

  const questions = [
    {
      questionText: "Is the account data entry?",
      answerOptions: [
        {answerText: "No", isCorrect: false, nextQuestionIndex: 1},
        {answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true, nextQuestionIndex: 6},
      ],
    },
    {
      questionText: "Is this customer 1 or 2?",
      answerOptions: [
        {answerText: "No", isCorrect: false, nextQuestionIndex: 2},
        {answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true, nextQuestionIndex: 2},
      ],
    },
    {
      questionText: "Is it someone with a Power of Attorney or Conservatorship for the Customer?",
      answerOptions: [
        {answerText: "No", isCorrect: false, nextQuestionIndex: 3},
        {answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true, nextQuestionIndex: 3},
      ],
    },
    {
      questionText: "Is it someone with a signed 'Name Add Form' on file?",
      answerOptions: [
        {answerText: "No", isCorrect: false, nextQuestionIndex: 4},
        {answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true, nextQuestionIndex: 4},
      ],
    },
    {
      questionText: "Is it someone who is verbally authorized by a verified account holder to speak?",
      answerOptions: [
        {answerText: "No", isCorrect: false, nextQuestionIndex: 5},
        {answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true, nextQuestionIndex: 5},
      ],
    },
    { //this is object number 5
      questionText: "VERIFIED",
      answerOptions: [
        {answerText: "No", isCorrect: false, nextQuestionIndex: 6},
        {answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true, nextQuestionIndex: 6},
      ],
    },
    { //this is object number 6
      questionText: "You can tell the customer their verbal password.",
      answerOptions: [
        {answerText: "No", isCorrect: false, nextQuestionIndex: 6},
        {answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true, nextQuestionIndex: 6},
      ],
    },
  ]

  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);

  const handleAnswerButton = (answerOption) => {
    const nextQuestion = answerOption.nextQuestionIndex;
    setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{questions[currentQuestion].questionText}</h1>
      
      <div className="answerSection">
        {questions[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map((answerOption)=> (
        <button onClick={()=>handleAnswerButton(answerOption)}>{answerOption.answerText}</button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store this data in the `questions` object. for example

```
{
  questionText: "Is the account data entry?",
  answerOptions: [
    {answerText: "No", isCorrect: false},
    {answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: 6}, // <====
  ],
},
```

and then

```
  const handleAnswerButton = (jumpToQuestion) => {
    const nextQuestion = jumpToQuestion || currentQuestion + 1;
    setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
  }
.
.
.
    <button onClick={ () => {
      handleAnswerButton(answerOption.jumpToQuestion)
      }}
    >{answerOption.answerText}</button>
```